# Ext Js - Problem Loading Two Grids

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to display two grids in a master/detail relationship. Being new to Ext JS, I've modified an example that will successfully display my data - either the master or the detail. But I can't get it to load them both. Each grid has it's own dataStore, columnModel and gridPanel.

Do I need to use different container to hold the gridPanels? Do I have a syntax error in the config for my Window? Thanks.

```
    OrdersGrid =  new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
      id: 'OrdersGrid',
      store: OrdersDataStore,
      cm: OrdersColumnModel,
      enableColLock:false,
      clicksToEdit:1,
      selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false})
    });

    ItemsGrid =  new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
      id: 'ItemsGrid',
      store: ItemsDataStore,
      cm: ItemsColumnModel,
      enableColLock:false,
      clicksToEdit:1,
      selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false})
    });

    OrdersItemsWindow = new Ext.Window({
      id: 'OrdersItemsWindow',
      title: 'Orders and Items',
      layout: 'vbox', 
      closable: true,
      height: 700,        
      width: 800,
      layoutConfig: {
        align : 'stretch',
        pack  : 'start',
      },
      plain: false,
      items: [ OrdersGrid, ItemsGrid ]
    });

    OrdersDataStore.load();
    ItemsDataStore.load();

    OrdersItemsWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The height of the two `GridPanels` needs to be set, since the `VBoxLayout` of the window doesn't handle this. It can only set the horizontal width of the items it contains.

For example:

```
OrdersGrid =  new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
  id: 'OrdersGrid',
  store: OrdersDataStore,
  cm: OrdersColumnModel,
  enableColLock:false,
  clicksToEdit:1,
  flex: 1,  // add this line
  selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:false})
});
```

The rest of the syntax you are using is correct.

Alternatively, it's possible to use something like `height: 200` to fix the height, in place of the `flex` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added to "items:[{OrdersGrid, flex:1},{ItemsGrid, height:400}]" in my Window config, but didn't get it to display (I get a blank page). Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var movieStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        baseParams: { action: 'movie' },
        fields: ["film_id","title", "rent", "buy"],
        data:   [{film_id:1,title: "film_A",rent: 20.0,buy: 30},
                {film_id:2,title: "film_B",rent: 20.0,buy: 36},
                {film_id:3,title: "film_C",rent :22.0,buy :27}]

    });
    var actorStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        baseParams: { action: 'actors' },
        fields: ["actor_id","name"],
        data:   [{actor_id: 1,name:"A"},
                {actor_id: 2,name: "B"},
                {actor_id: 3,name :"C"}]

    });

   var movieGrid = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
        store: movieStore,
        //sm: Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel',{ singleSelect: true }),
        singleSelect: true,

        title: "Movies",
        selType: 'rowmodel',
       /* plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })],*/

        columnLines: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        columns: [
                  {xtype : "rownumberer"},
                  {text: 'film_ID',dataIndex: 'film_id'},
                  {text: 'Movie',dataIndex: 'title', editor: 'textfield'},
            {text: 'Rent', dataIndex: 'rent',xtype : "numbercolumn",format:"0.00"},
            {text: 'Buy', dataIndex: 'buy',xtype:"numbercolumn",format:"0.00"}


      ],
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        margin: '0 0 20 0',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

  var actorGrid =  Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
        store: actorStore,
        //sm: Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel',{ singleSelect: true }),
        singleSelect: true,

        title: "Actor",
        selType: 'rowmodel',
       /* plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })],*/

        columnLines: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        columns: [
                  {xtype : "rownumberer"},
                  {text: 'actor_id',dataIndex: 'actor_id'},
                  {text: 'name',dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},



      ],
        iconCls: 'icon-grid',
        margin: '0 0 20 0',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

  movieGrid.getSelectionModel().on('rowselect',
            function(sm, rowIndex, record) {
            /*moviesGrid.setTitle('Movies starring ' +
            record.data.first_name + ' ' + record.data.last_name);*/
            actorStore.load({ params: { 'movie':
            record.data.actor_id} });
            });
            movieStore.load();

});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did to make this solution work? generally speaking, "code-only" answers are less helpful than ones with explanation.